# Creating VLANs on a PowerConnect 8132

Tags: vlan, dell-powerconnect

I have scoured all over dell.com for answers and nothing that really explained/taught me how to do what I want.

I have 1 PowerConnect 8131 Layer 3 switch.

My router is connected to port 1 and it gives my VLAN1 (default vlan) the IP of:

`192.168.86.1 (gateway)`

I need to create 3 VLANs,

1 - *Management (tagged)*

2 - *Data (tagged)*

3 - *Access (untagged)*

I have been able to learn/figure out how to make VLANs

`config#en`
`config#config`
`config#vlan 10,20,30`

I have assigned ports `3-6,9-12,17-20` to `VLAN 10`, `7,13,21` to `VLAN 20`, and `8,14,22` to `VLAN 30`

From here I am confused, what IP address would/should I give to each `VLAN` and how would I let each `VLAN` send traffic thru each other, as well as be able to connect to the internet.

I have reset the switch so many times just to start from scratch redoing all the steps hoping I might have missed or misread some tutorial. please help.

Comment: How many hosts per VLAN you will use?

Answer (score 0):

> From here I am confused, what IP address would/should I give to each VLAN

It doesn't particularly matter. You can just assign them non-overlapping network in RFC1918 space. For example, 192.168.20.0/24 for one and 192.168.30.0/24 for the other.

> and how would I let each VLAN send traffic thru each other, as well as be able to connect to the internet.

You need a router to do that. Most layer 3 switches can also act as routers. The usual process for using a switch is a router is as follows:

1. Configure a virtual interface for each VLAN.
2. Assign each virtual interface an IP address inside its corresponding VLAN.
3. Make sure each device has an appropriate routing table so that it can reach the other VLANs. For example, if you assign VLAN 20 the 192.168.20.0/24 network and the switch interface in that VLAN gets 192.168.20.1, it may make sense for machines inside that network and VLAN to have 192.168.20.1 as their default route.

Answer (score 0):

VLANs is needed to isolate different networks in one switch. Vlan can't be tagged or untagged. Only ip packets can be tagged by VLAN ID. You can allow or disallow ip traffic by VLAN ID, which can go through switche's port. Port can work in three modes:

- access - port sends outgoing ip packets from one allowed VLAN without
  VLAN ID tag (untagged traffic);
- trunk - port sends outgoing ip packets from one or several allowed VLANs with VLAN ID tags (tagged traffic);
- hybrid - port sends outgoing ip packets from one allowed VLAN without VLAN ID tag (untagged traffic) and sends outgoing ip packets from one
  or several allowed VLANs with VLAN ID tags (tagged traffic).